# how to give relative image path in Html String?

Tags: html, react-native

I am working on a react native project, and generating a PDF from HTML String. In that HTML, I am displaying an image from my project folder but don't how to give the image path correctly.

```
    <html>
    <body style="justifyContent: 'center'">
    <div style=" height: 100px;
        width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
        <img src='./Module/assets/someImage.png'  align="top" style="width:80px;height:80px;"/>
        <Text align="center" style = "padding-Top: 5px; font-size: 32px; margin-left: 10px;font-weight: bold;"> 
            Technical Interview Assessment Sheet</Text>
    </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nxPc.png)

Comment: project File structure screenshot would be a much better help

Comment: @SundeepPidugu I updated my Question with a screenshot.

Comment: `assets/someImage.png` would do fine.

Comment: It's not working. I don't know why? Actually I am using 'react-native-html-to-pdf' 3rd party in react native, and it is using HTML as a String. Just because of this it might not be working. right?